# php-nuke date display on the main footer of news

Tags: php, footer

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add "post date" on the main footer of News. I have to click on "more" icon whenever I wanna check the date of my posts.I need to have it on the main footer.

guess I found where the related codes are. They are in theme.php:

main footer:

```
  <div class="NewsFooter">
    <div class="foot-r">
    <?=$MoreLinkRight?>
    </div>
    <div class="foot-l">
    <?=$MoreLinkLeft?>
    </div>
    <div class="foot-m">

      <div class="Author">
        <?=_AUTHOR?>
        :
        <?=$aid?>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?=_VISIT?>
        :
        <?=$counter?>
      </div>
```

sub-footer (which is a conditional):

```
<?php
}


function themearticle($aid, $informant, $datetime, $title, $bodytext, $hometext, $topics, $topicname_link, $topicimage_link, $topictext_link, $printpage, $notes, $counter, $score, $ratings, $sid, $topic_link)
{
    global $admin, $tipath;
    $ThemeSel = get_theme();
    theme_lang();
    if(file_exists("themes/$ThemeSel/images/topics/$topicimage_link")){
    $t_image = "themes/$ThemeSel/images/topics/$topicimage_link";
    }else{
    $t_image = "$tipath$topicimage_link";
    }
    $posted = ""._POSTEDON." $datetime "._BY." "; 
    $posted .= get_author($aid);
    $notes = str_replace(" ","_",$notes);
    $notes = explode(":",$notes);
    foreach($notes as $tag){
        $tags .= "<i><a href=\"modules.php?name=News&file=tags&tags=$tag\">".str_replace("_"," ",$tag)."</a></i> ";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

WOW... I made it...

I just added

```
> <?=$datetime?>
```

under

```
> <?=_AUTHOR?>
```

and baAm.
I dunno where this idea came from but it's working and that's all that matters.
Thanks anyway...